# How does Phaser 3 calculate the y position on top of the platforms every time?

Tags: javascript, logic, phaser-framework, calculation

I am doing a Phaser 3 tutorial (javascript framework for making 2d and 3d games) and I am interested to know how Phaser 3 processes the y position from this simple calculation:

```
    /**
     * @param {Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite} Sprite
     */
    addCarrotAbove(sprite)
     {
        // this one!!!!!
        const y = sprite.y - sprite.displayHeight

        /** @type {Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite} */
        const carrot = this.carrots.get(sprite.x, y, 'carrot')

        this.add.existing(carrot)

        carrot.body.setSize(carrot.width, carrot.height)

        return carrot
    }
```

and when parsing a different object to this function, which instead of the sprite is an automatic platform recycling thing that I wrote / iteration:

````
```update(t, dt)
    {
        this.platforms.children.iterate(child => {
            /** @type {Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite} */
            const platform = child

            const scrollY = this.cameras.main.scrollY
            if (platform.y >= scrollY + 600)
            {
                platform.y = scrollY - 60
                platform.body.updateFromGameObject()

                // create a carrot above the platform being reused
                this.addCarrotAbove(platform)
            }
        })```
````

it automatically places the carrots on top of the platforms (when executing the function)

How does it do it? The only line I'm interested in is the y variable I created with const. The position of the carrot gets calculated with that simple calculation, but I can't understand how it puts the carrot on top of the platform each time. Thanks stackoverflow community!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. For anyone that has the same issue and can't, the recycling platform function I wrote uses the camera scroll to send the platforms upwards, and that gives the Y coordinate a negative value. In order to spawn the carrot not inside the platform (which would be sprite.y) and over the platform, you SUBTRACT the sprite display height and not add the two because the sprite.y is a negative value, and by subtracting it you are sending the carrot upward the amount the display height amount of pixels. Hope I helped.